# UIPageViewController has strange size

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I am using a `UIPageViewController` in my app.
It works quite well, but  when I turn pages, the next page seems to get initialized in a frame that is bigger than the screen: While turning the page, only a part of the view of the next `viewController` fits on the screen.

I am initializing the `UIPageViewController` in `viewDidLoad` and started to log the frames of the `PageVC`, its subviews and the `parentVC`. Every frame seems to be okay, only the `UIPageViewController'`s frame, which I log in `viewControllerAfterViewController` has a width that is nearly the double of the screen's actual size.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I finally solved this issue by setting the right frame to the `UIPageViewController`'s view when initializing the PageVC:

```
pageViewController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
```

Where `pageViewController` is the `UIPageViewController` I initialize,
and self is the parent VC of the pageVC.

Hope this helps anyone with similar problems.

Comment: Actually, this works fine as long as frame top and left are 0, otherwise, the PageViewController will not be correctly aligned (it will be shifted to the bottom/right). It's safer to set just width and height like:

`pageViewController.view.width = self.view.width  
pageViewController.view.height = self.view.height`

Comment: @Cristina : `width` is not a member of `UIView`. I would prefer `pageViewController.view.frame.size = self.view.frame.size`

Comment: @LaurentMaquet yes you're right, `width` and `height` were removed as direct members of UIView in a recent Swift version (4 if I remember correctly). Furthermore now I would suggest to use `pageViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds` in place of setting `width` and `height` separately because `bounds` returns the view's `frame` without the offset from the origin. Thank you very much!