# xCode 6 using UIPageViewController and swift changing view size

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I'm loading views into a UIPageViewController and scrolling through them horizontally.
My issue is that when a view enters screen, it has a bigger size, and when the scroll finishes, it snaps to the size it should have.
Been trying to figure this out for a couple of hours now.
Anyone has had the same problem? how did you solve it?

I've checked these 2 links:
[UIPageViewController changes size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223932/uipageviewcontroller-changes-size)
[UIPageViewController has strange size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998322/uipageviewcontroller-has-strange-size)

That made sense, but on my case, by doing that, I made the views too big on smaller devices, feels like the constraints aren't working, so I'm getting the bigger size here

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this:

```
// Disalbe translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints
self.pageViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

// Set up page view controller view constraints by using PureLayout
[self.pageViewController.view autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero]
```

Comment: It stays the same :( I was already doing this with the constrains, I believe this is the same but with code right?

Answer (score 0):

```
please confine  is it help ful or not ..




 - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
    {
        ImageViewController *contentVc = (ImageViewController *)viewController;

        NSUInteger currentIndex = [_modelArray indexOfObject:[contentVc model]];
        _vcIndex = currentIndex;
        [_rateStepper setValue:[[contentVc model] rating]];
        ImageModel *model = [_modelArray objectAtIndex:_vcIndex];
        [_imageLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - Rating: %d", model.imageName, model.rating]];

        if (currentIndex == 0)
        {
            return nil;
        }

        ImageViewController *imageViewController = [[ImageViewController alloc] init];
        imageViewController.model = [_modelArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex - 1];
        return imageViewController;
    }

    - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
    {
        ImageViewController *contentVc = (ImageViewController *)viewController;

        NSUInteger currentIndex = [_modelArray indexOfObject:[contentVc model]];
        _vcIndex = currentIndex;
        [_rateStepper setValue:[[contentVc model] rating]];
        ImageModel *model = [_modelArray objectAtIndex:_vcIndex];
        [_imageLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - Rating: %d", model.imageName, model.rating]];

        if (currentIndex == _modelArray.count - 1)
        {
            return nil;
        }

        ImageViewController *imageViewController = [[ImageViewController alloc] init];
        imageViewController.model = [_modelArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex + 1];
        return imageViewController;
    }


    If you build and run now, the pages will scroll, however we are still missing the page indicator view. We only need to implement the following dataSource methods as below:



    - (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
    {
        return _modelArray.count;
    }

    - (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Not at all, the scrolling works perfect, the problem is the size snap

Comment: self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);
 try this ..